# Issue with SELECT using Angular and ASP.NET Web API and EF Code First

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, select, data-binding, asp.net-web-api

I am having issues getting a SELECT to work with Angular, ASP.NET Web API v2 and Entity Framework Code First.  I have two simple objects, Products and Categories, defined with the following models:

```
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string SerialNumber { get; set; }
    public string Notes { get; set; }
    public Category Category { get; set; }
    public ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
}

public class Category
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ApplicationUser User { get; set; }

}
```

I then have the following Angular Markup:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputSerial" class="col-lg-3 control-label">Category</label>
    <div class="col-lg-9">
        <select class="form-control" id="selectCategory" ng-model="product.Category" ng-options="category as category.Name for category in categories"></select>
    </div>
</div>
```

And finally, the following Angular app.js script:

```
app.controller('SerialController', function ($scope, $http, $routeParams, $cookies) {

    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'http://localhost:20697/api/categories/' + '?access_token=' + $cookies.token,
        headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + $cookies.token }
    }).success(function (data, status, headers) {
        $scope.categories = data;
    }).error(function (data, status, headers) {
        $scope.error = reason;
    });

    var onGetComplete = function (response) {
        $scope.product = response.data;
    };

    var onError = function (reason) {
        $scope.error = reason;
    };

    if ($routeParams.id > 0) {

        $http.get("http://localhost:20697/api/products/" + $routeParams.id)
            .then(onGetComplete, onError);
    }

    $scope.saveProduct = function () {

        if ($scope.product.Id > 0) {
            $http({
                method: 'PUT',
                data: $scope.product,
                url: 'http://localhost:20697/api/products/' + $scope.product.Id
            }).success(function (data, status, headers) {

            }).error(function (data, status, headers) {

            });
        }
        else {
            $http({
                method: 'POST',
                data: $scope.product,
                url: 'http://localhost:20697/api/products/'
            }).success(function (data, status, headers) {

            }).error(function (data, status, headers) {

            });
        }
    };
});
```

With this, I am getting the SELECT to populate correctly, with the categories from the database.  However, I have two issues.

Issue #1)  If the category is set in the database, it is being sent from the web api to Angular, but it is not actually selecting the correct entry in the select.

Issue #2)  When I select an entry in the drop down listing, and save, angular is sending the product object back to the api with the correct category set.  I can even see it in the api controller.  However it is not actually saving the category select to the product in the database.  Here is my controller code for the update of product:

```
// PUT: api/Products/5
[ResponseType(typeof(void))]
public IHttpActionResult PutProduct(int id, Product product)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }

    if (id != product.Id)
    {
        return BadRequest();
    }

    db.Entry(product).State = EntityState.Modified;

    try
    {
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
    catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
    {
        if (!ProductExists(id))
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        else
        {
            throw;
        }
    }

    return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
}
```

In the actual database, Entity Framework Code first added the category in the products table as Category_Id, which I would have expected.

Any help on this would be appreciated.  Thanks!

UPDATE:  After the suggestions below not working quite right, I did some more searching online.  I found this post from Scott Allen.  http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2013/06/19/using-ngoptions-in-angularjs.aspx.  From that, I was able to use my original code, but then add some code in the angular controller to do the initial selection.  I also had to change the order of things in the controller (and I need to refactor it further once I get this working).  Here is the updated portion of the controller:

```
$http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'http://localhost:20697/api/categories/' + '?access_token=' + $cookies.token,
    headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + $cookies.token }
}).success(function (data, status, headers) {
    $scope.categories = data;
    if ($routeParams.id > 0) {
        $http.get("http://localhost:20697/api/products/" + $routeParams.id)
            .then(onGetComplete, onError);
    }
}).error(function (data, status, headers) {
    $scope.error = reason;
});

var onGetComplete = function (response) {
    $scope.product = response.data;

    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.categories.length; i++) {
        if ($scope.categories[i].Id == $scope.product.Category.Id) {
            $scope.product.Category = $scope.categories[i];
            break;
        }
    }
};
```

With this, I am now able to get the initial selection working, and the correct category selection is getting sent back to the API.  **The issue is, that for whatever reason Entity Framework is skipping the category selection when updating product.  Here is the T-SQL that is getting executed:**

```
DECLARE @2 AS SQL_VARIANT;
DECLARE @0 AS SQL_VARIANT;
DECLARE @1 AS SQL_VARIANT;
SET @2 = NULL;
SET @0 = NULL;
SET @1 = NULL;

UPDATE [dbo].[Products]
SET [Name] = @0, [SerialNumber] = @1, [Notes] = NULL
WHERE ([Id] = @2)
```

As you can see, Category_Id is not getting updated at all.  Is there something I have to do to tell EF that it should update the foreign key for category as well as the product information?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after continuing to dig around and try things.  It looks like this was caused by me having only a navigation property and no foreign key back to the categories table.  I really don't like this solution, but it works.  I consider two things hacks and would love it if someone could give me some thoughts on better ways to fix.

Step one to fix:  I had to update my Product class to include a foreign key reference to category:

```
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string SerialNumber { get; set; }
    public string Notes { get; set; }

    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
    public ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
}
```

Then after having all sorts of painful struggles with getting Entity Framework to update my database, I created a brand new database and it worked.  Instead of the database now having a column Category_Id in the products table, it now had a CategoryId as expected.  My first thought to this is yuck.  I would really prefer NOT have this extra property to deal with.

Step Two to Fix:  This is a by-product of adding the other category.  I am sure I could fix it by changing my ng-model and ng-options to use CategoryId instead of the object.  But for the sake of time I went ahead and added the following code to the ProductsController on the update:

```
if (product.Category.Id != product.CategoryId)
{
    product.CategoryId = product.Category.Id;
}
```

**Ideally.. if I could leave my model the way it was, and only have a navigation property, that would be best.  Perhaps I would add the foreign key via annotations.  If anyone has thoughts on how to better this, please let me know.**

Thanks!

Comment: I tried to remove the foreign key from the Product class, and instead specify it in the OnModelBuilding() method using fluent API.  However, even though it appeared like EF liked the FK that way, it still ignored the update.  Sounds like the solution above is going to have to do.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an idea for the angular part of your question. We've had issues trying to using objects in select boxes. In Angular ngModel compares by reference, not value. This is important when binding to an array of objects. I'm guessing your item isn't being selected because your references are different. We now write our ng-option expression like this:

```
<select ng-model="product.category.id" ng-option="category.id as category.Name for category in categories" />
```

Instead of matching the entire object this will allow you to just match the id or some other property which in our opinion is a little be cleaner.  Hope this helps!

UPDATE

Try this and see if it works for you:

View Update:

```
<select ng-model="categoryId" ng-option="category.id as category.Name for category in categories" />
```

Controller Update:

```
app.controller('SerialController', function ($scope, $http, $routeParams, $cookies) {
$scope.categoryId = 0;

$http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'http://localhost:20697/api/categories/' + '?access_token=' + $cookies.token,
    headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + $cookies.token }
}).success(function (data, status, headers) {
    $scope.categories = data;
}).error(function (data, status, headers) {
    $scope.error = reason;
});

var onGetComplete = function (response) {
    $scope.product = response.data;
    $scope.categoryId = $scope.product.category.Id;
};

var onError = function (reason) {
    $scope.error = reason;
};

if ($routeParams.id > 0) {

    $http.get("http://localhost:20697/api/products/" + $routeParams.id)
        .then(onGetComplete, onError);
}

$scope.saveProduct = function () {
    $scope.product.category.Id = $scope.categoryId;

    if ($scope.product.Id > 0) {
        $http({
            method: 'PUT',
            data: $scope.product,
            url: 'http://localhost:20697/api/products/' + $scope.product.Id
        }).success(function (data, status, headers) {

        }).error(function (data, status, headers) {

        });
    }
    else {
        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            data: $scope.product,
            url: 'http://localhost:20697/api/products/'
        }).success(function (data, status, headers) {

        }).error(function (data, status, headers) {

        });
    }
};
```

});

Comment: So that did fix the first question, but made the second part worse.  It does now bind correctly and select the correct entry, but now it is no longer sending back the correct selection to the api on save.

Comment: What does the product object look like after a selection is made? What specific property is not being updated?

Comment: Not sure if this will help or not, but you probably need to fix the  check you are doing to see if the product id is greater than 0 when saving so the id property is lower cased. $scope.product.id

Comment: With the changes you recommended if the product was initially set with the category id = 5 "MSDN" for example.  MSDN shows correctly when loading the page.  However, after I switch it to id = 6, "Media/Graphics", and click save, the product sent still has the original id5 "MSDN" set on the way back to the API.

Comment: Check out the update I made to the answer. See if that helps.

Comment: That got me part of the way again, but still could not get it to solve the entire problem.  I did some searching further and made some changes that got me very close.  I updated my original post with the additional details.  It looks to me like I am completely into an EF issue at this point.

Comment: Your mods now allow you to compare your category objects by reference correctly.  That's why it works now.  Wish I could help with the EF part but I'm not strong in that area.

Comment: I greatly appreciate all the help you provided!  Thanks a bunch!